# a problem about singleton in ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

i am a newbie about ruby.
should not the singleton class`s initialize function have any arguments?
here is my code:

```
require 'singleton'
class AAA
    attr :string , true
    include Singleton 
    def initialize(stirng)
        @string = "aaa";
    end
end 
a = AAA.instance("simpleton");
puts a.string
```

i think should be correct.but the ruby also tell me :

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

```
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `instance'
```

T___T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a singleton there's no need for passing any parameters to initialize, because it will always return the same object.

If you want to change something on the class everytime you call it you could define a new method.

```
require 'singleton'
class AAA
    attr :string , true
    include Singleton 
    def initialize
        @string = "aaa";
    end
    def self.change(string)
      instance.string = string
      instance
    end
end 
a = AAA.change("simpleton");
puts a.string
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but there are plenty of other ways to get a singleton instance without using the Singleton module.

I personally like this method:

```
class Foo
  def self.instance
    @__instance__ ||= new
  end
end
```

If you could give a little more information about **why** you're trying to do what you're doing it might be helpful.

Comment: If you're studying you should also read up on why the singleton pattern is "bad".  It's not such a big deal in languages like ruby but in java/C# it's not recommended.

Comment: It's absolutely not thread safe, but if you're not using threads or doing your initialization up front then it's ok.  Plus, if the question is academic I doubt the question asker is concerned about thread safety.